# Cannot subscript a value of type '[CustomObject]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

we have json data that is put into a custom object:

```
 "sentMoney": [
                {
                    "amount": 3840.83,
                    "currency": "MXN",
                    "isMajor": false
                },
                {
                    "amount": 200,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "isMajor": true
                }
        ]

public final class SentMoney: NSCoding {
  public var currency: String?
  public var isMajor: Bool? = false
  public var amount: Double?
}
```

the custom object is then made reference to in a variable:

```
 public var sentMoney: [SentMoney]?
```

Now what we are trying to do is only get the FIRST amount (3840.83).

I tried doing it this way but there were errors:

```
 let amountsOnlyArray = self.postTransferSuccess?.sentMoney.map({ $0["amount"] })//Error -Cannot subscript a value of type '[SentMoney]' with an index of type 'String' 
 let firstAmountOnly = self.postTransferSuccess?.sentMoney![0]["amount"]//Error -Type 'BSentMoney' has no subscript members
```

Is there a better way to get that first amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the variable sentMoney explicitly declared as [SentMoney], you can directly use the properties of the objects while mapping the array or when indexed for an element, like below.

```
let amountsOnlyArray = self.postTransferSuccess?.sentMoney.map({ $0.amount })
```

or

```
let firstAmountOnly = self.postTransferSuccess?.sentMoney![0].amount
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're parsing the JSON into an object want to access the property from the object. You should access it with dot notation e.g. `$0.amount`

```
let amountsOnlyArray = self.postTransferSuccess?.sentMoney.map({ $0.amount })
let firstAmountOnly = self.postTransferSuccess?.sentMoney![0].amount
```

**Edit**

Here's a more comprehensive example:

```
class SentMoney {
    public var currency: String?
    public var isMajor: Bool? = false
    public var amount: Double?
}

let one = SentMoney()
one.amount = 1.2

let two = SentMoney()
two.amount = 3.4

let sentMoney = [one, two]

let amountsOnlyArray = sentMoney.map({ $0.amount })

amountsOnlyArray // [{some 1.2}, {some 3.4}]

sentMoney.first?.amount // 1.2
```

Comment: Strange I get an error "Value of type '[SentMoney]' has no member 'amount'" on the first line

Comment: That sounds like you are calling `.amount` directly on the array instead of getting the first object. Maybe you can share the code you are using to create your array of SentMoney objects?

Comment: The second constant worked directly, no need for the first constant!